# How to import text from one JS file and then pass that dynamically as prop values to a component defined in a different file; in react js?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, onclick, react-props

I have a tree.js file that looks like this:
(the values to be taken as prop values have been mentioned in comments)

```
const treeData = {
  'first-level-node-1': {           
    label: 'Phytophthora agathicida',
    index: 0, 
    nodes: {
      'Phyag_NZFS3770': {
        label: 'Phyag_NZFS3770', // prop value 1
        index: 0, },
        'Phyag_NZFS3772':{
          label: 'Phyag_NZFS3772', // prop value 2
          index:0,
        }
    },
   
  },
  'first-level-node-2': {
    label: 'Phytophthora aleatoria',
    index: 1,
    nodes:{
      'Phyal_NZFS4037': {
        label: 'Phyal_NZFS4037', // prop value 3
        index: 2, },
  },},
// and so on
}
```

So I want to take the above mentioned node labels as various prop values and pass them dynamically to a component in a Nav.js file as shown below:

```
function NAV() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/jbrowse/jbrowse' render={(props) => <View {...props} id={} />} />
```

I want to dynamically add values ('Phyal_NZFS4037', 'Phyag_NZFS3772' etc) to the props id as shown here

The 'View' function component is defined in another JS file, a snippet of which is shown below. The props id value passed to View component in the Nav.js file will be passed on to this.

```
import React from 'react'
import 'fontsource-roboto'
import {
  createViewState,
  JBrowseLinearGenomeView,
} from '@jbrowse/react-linear-genome-view'

function View(props) {

  const fasta= require(`../genome_data/${props.id}.fna`)  
  const fai= require(`../genome_data/${props.id}.fna.fai`)
  const gff= require(`../genome_data/${props.id}.sorted.gff.gz`)
  const gfftbi = require(`../genome_data/${props.id}.sorted.gff.gz.tbi`)
  const ssrbw = require(`../genome_data/${props.id}.bw`)
  // const rxlr = require(`../genome_data/${props.id}.rxlr.bw`)

const assembly ={
  name: `${props.id}`,
sequence: {
  type: 'ReferenceSequenceTrack',
  trackId: 'GRCh38-ReferenceSequenceTrack',
  adapter: {
    type: 'IndexedFastaAdapter',
    fastaLocation: {
      uri: fasta,
        
    },
    faiLocation: {
      uri: fai,
    },
    
  },
},
aliases: ['hg38'],}
```

Can anyone please suggest a way to do this? As a biologist who is absolutely new to all this, who needs to meet a deadline; I desperately need your help.

Comment: Could you give an example of the result you want

Comment: Could you describe your use case? What do you want to achieve as an end result?

Comment: I have made some edits to my original post, is it understandable now? Thanks a lot guys